# How to call migration on job, properly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this managing institution project. Each institution has its own DB like '**institution_1**', '**institution_2**' etc. I'm creating that institution DB and trying to migrate into them after I created them. Because it takes to long to migrate (I think bc it has a lot of tables) I'm using queue and jobs. Job is running but not the migration!!

*Controller: *

```
$newDb = DB::connection('rc')->statement("CREATE DATABASE intitution_$institutionId CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;");
    DB::connection('rc')->statement("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `institution\\_$institutionId`.* TO 'institutions'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION");

    if ($newDb) {
      Config::set('database.connections.th', [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'institution_'.$institutionId,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'timezone' => '+00:00',
        'strict' => false,
      ]);
      $job = (new CreateInstitutionDb())->delay(Carbon::now()->addSecond(120));
      dispatch($job);
      return true;
}
```

*CreateInstitutionDb Job: *

```
public function handle()
{
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('migrate',['--database' => 'th', '--force' => true]);

}
```

Comment: How can you tell the job is running? log something in the handle function of the job to see

Comment: Because of jobTable in main database